# Sea Routes shipment Dataset Caribbean South America, Free

Tags: data

I would like to obtain gis data of cargo, container vessels as well as small cargo inter-islands ships and for an educational non commercial project/publication on food trade across the Caribbean Sea. Any information available.

Comment: It sounds like you are after [opendata.se].

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AIS data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system).

I'm not sure for the coverage of the caribbean sea and the temporal extent. IMO it is difficult to get historical data for free, but for a start you could work with [AIS data from NOAA](https://marinecadastre.gov/data/) (..into the blue: Puerto Rico and Panama Channel). For the caribbean sea you will have a poor station AIS infastructure (in logging terms).

Commercial sites like vesselfinder.com, vesseltracker.com and marintraffic.com offer also historical databases and show more stations.

[image]

To mine the cargo (drought) and ship type info's you could parse/read [AIS Message 1 and 5](https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?pageName=AISMessages). In Message 5 you will find DST (Destination) and ETA (Estimated Time of arrival). The are several AIS decoder available in the web. [Kurt Schwehr](https://github.com/schwehr/libais) has a good repository at github.